# Automatically arrange file structure to match Solution Folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions, project-structure

I'm using a Solution Folder in Visual Studio 2013.

Per the common 'complaint' about solution folders it does not align with the filesystem so all the added files are currently floating about in the solution directory.

I am looking for a process in VS *or* tool (eg. an extension) that would allow the automated process of adjusting the filesystem files/folders to match that of the Solutions Folder layout - starting/running the process manually is acceptable.